# IL emitting at runtime vs JIT

Tags: c#, .net

Is IL emmiting **at runtime** causes the emitted code to be compiled by JIT compiler?

For example: Based on this (https://blog.codinghorror.com/to-compile-or-not-to-compile) explanation of how regex compile option works, will it compile to target architecture (i.e x86 instruction set) or will IL emitted be just interpreted by the runtime?

Comment: IL is always jitted by the CLR, the CLR never interprets it (at least MS .net, Mono is a different story)